# How to redirect to default/thanks with Javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress, forms, redirect

I am using contact form 7 on Wordpress on two pages (same form, two different pages) and would like to redirect to the respective .../thanks on each.

Using the following javascript:

> on_sent_ok: "location.replace('/thanks');"

It redirects to domain.com/thanks, where I would like it to go to domain.com/page1/thanks or domain.com/page2/thanks when they fill out the for on page1 or page2.

How do I change the javascript to do that without having to implement two different forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the `/`, it tells the navigator that what you're giving him is an absolute path from your domain.

So just do: `on_sent_ok: "location.replace('thanks');"`

That is if you're on some `yourdomainname.com/somepage` and want to go to `yourdomainname.com/thanks`. If you want to go to `yourdomainname.com/somepage/thanks`, then one solution is to concatenate your path complement to the current path:

```
on_sent_ok: "location.replace(location + '/thanks');"
```

**EDIT:**
It seems changing the pathname inside location works too. It will completely ignore any GET variables present in the URL.

```
on_sent_ok: "location.pathname += "/thanks";"
```

This will take you from `yourdomainname.com/somepage?gclid=XYZ` to `yourdomainname.com/somepage/thanks?gclid=XYZ`.

Comment: Actually, now my issue is that since we are driving traffic from AdWords to it it adds a ?gclid to the landing page URL (yourdomainname.com/somepage?gclid=XYZ). So basically now it adds the /thanks after the gclid which does not do anything.... How can I make it remove the gclid?

Comment: Great that worked! Thanks a lot! (et je connaissais un Antoine Combes a Cergy-Pontoise, mais j'imagine que c'est un nom courant :) )

Comment: Je suis originaire du Val d'Oise, mais ça m'étonnerait beaucoup que ça ait été moi :)

Comment: J' y etais a l'ESSEC.. Trouve moi sur Linkedin ou Facebook, si tu es celui que je pense le monde est bien petit!

Answer (score 0):

You could provide the exact URL instead of doing a replacement:

```js
on_sent_ok: "window.location.replace('http://www.example.com/');"
```

Comment: isn't that awfully static ?